# What is the limit of $\left(\frac{\sqrt[n]{a}+b}{b+1}\right)^n$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Assume $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers prove that:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{\sqrt[n]{a}+b}{b+1}\right)^n = a^{1/(b+1)}$

Actually the main question was longer than this but the other states of the problem were easier but this part I am stuck...
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Using the basic limits $\lim_{x\to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{x})^x =e$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{a^x -1}{x}=\ln a$ and it remains for you to express your sequence under these form.

Comment: Alternatively, note that $a^{1/n} \to 1$ since $a>0$. Take logarithms, use L'Hospital, and appeal to the continuity of $\exp$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always remember that $x^y=\exp(y\log x)$. So we need to show that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \exp\left(n\cdot\log\frac{\sqrt[n]{a}+b}{b+1}\right) = \exp\left(\frac{\log a}{b+1}\right)\text.$$

Since $\exp$ is continuous, this is equivalent to

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n\cdot\log\frac{\sqrt[n]{a}+b}{b+1} = \frac{\log a}{b+1}\text.$$

Proof:

Substituting $n=1/t$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n\cdot\log\frac{\sqrt[n]{a}+b}{b+1} = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\log\frac{\exp(t\cdot\log a)+b}{b+1}}t\underset{\text{l'Hôpital}}{=}\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\left(\log\frac{\exp(t\cdot\log a)+b}{b+1}\right)'}{t'}=\\ 
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+} \left(\log\frac{\exp(t\cdot\log a)+b}{b+1}\right)'=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{b+1}{\exp(t\cdot\log a)+b}\cdot\frac{\log a\cdot\exp(t\cdot\log a)}{b+1}=\frac{\log a}{b+1}$$

where the last equality follows by simply plugging in $t=0$, since $\exp$ is continuous in $0$.

Comment: I just realized that this becomes more elegant with the substitution $n=\frac{\log a}{t}$ instead of $n=\frac 1t$, but you can do this yourself.